# how to protect against TLS GOLDENDOODLE with c++ and openssl?

Tags: c++, security, ssl, openssl

have a simple web server made with C++ and openssl, and when running [SSL Lab's SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=fuviewer.ml) on it, it informs me that the server is vulnerable to `GOLDENDOODLE` and `Sleeping POODLE` (among other things, screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7ZgP.png)),

i'm running libopenssl 1.1.1c, which is the latest openssl release as of writing, so i don't think it's a case of `using an old outdated vulnerable TLS library`, instead i'm probably just using it wrong,
 hence the question: how do you protect against GOLDENDOODLE with openssl? here is the entire (vulnerable?) server source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

const uint16_t port=443;
int create_socket(const uint16_t port)
{
    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0)
    {
        perror("Unable to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Unable to bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(s, 1) < 0)
    {
        perror("Unable to listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return s;
}

void init_openssl()
{
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
}

void cleanup_openssl()
{
    EVP_cleanup();
}

SSL_CTX *create_context()
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    method = SSLv23_server_method();

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (!ctx)
    {
        perror("Unable to create SSL context");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ctx;
}

void configure_context(SSL_CTX *ctx)
{
//     - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
//   /etc/letsencrypt/live/fuviewer.ml/fullchain.pem
//   Your key file has been saved at:
//   /etc/letsencrypt/live/fuviewer.ml/privkey.pem

    (void)ctx;

    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);

    /* Set the key and cert */
    // SSL_FILETYPE_PEM
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, "fullchain.pem") <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "privkey.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    int sock;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    init_openssl();
    ctx = create_context();

    configure_context(ctx);

    sock = create_socket(port);
    std::cout << "server running!" << std::flush;
    /* Handle connections */
    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL *ssl;
        const char reply[] =
            "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
            "Test-header: Yep\r\n"
            "Content-Length: 3\r\n"
            "\r\n"
            "abc";
        const auto reply_size=sizeof(reply)-1;
        int client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
        if (client < 0)
        {
            perror("Unable to accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);

        if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0)
        {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        }
        else
        {
            if(SSL_write(ssl, reply, reply_size)!=reply_size)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("FAILED TO SEND ALL BYTES");
            };
            {
                // openssl gets cranky if we don't try to read at least 1 byte, even tho we don't really want to..
                uint8_t unused;
                SSL_read(ssl,&unused,sizeof(unused));
            }
            SSL_shutdown(ssl);
            //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
        SSL_free(ssl);
        close(client);
    }
    close(sock);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    cleanup_openssl();
}
```

Comment: Why not click on "MORE INFO" links on that page and find out? Why not Google the vulns and find out?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i'm all for googling it, and when i find a solution, i may answer this question myself if nobody else has by then. but is it your opinion that this question should not have an answer on stackoverflow?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I find your comment not helpful since "MORE INFO" does not provide any obvious information which can actually be used to solve this specific problem. If you can find such information there please answer the question or at least provide a link to these information.

Comment: Please show evidence of your research so far. You know how this works!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  i think i have to tell openssl to disable all (or some?) CBC-based ciphers. I don't know how to do that though, and now i gotta go afk to eat dinner.

Comment: Now we have something we can work with :) Ask _that_ question and we can start looking at the OpenSSL docs to find out how to accomplish that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: while disabling all CBC ciphers would solve the problem it is not the case that every use of CBC has this problem. If for example GOLDENDOODLE is exploitable depends not only on the support for CBC but also on the specific implementation. See also https://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/vert/goldendoodle-attack/. And, disabling any CBC  ciphers might actually cause problems with providing support for older clients so this is not a practical solution in the first place.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Tell the OP, not me

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry, but your argument was to just look at MORE INFO, implying that everything should be obvious from there. It is not and there are actually very few information online about this problem - usually resulting in the conclusion that OpenSSL should not be vulnerable to these problems in the first place.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I wasn't making an "argument". I was trying to persuade the OP to do at least the most basic research in order to produce a good question that meets our quality standards, as I'm sure you know. Never did I claim that clicking "MORE INFO" will suddenly reveal the perfect answer in glorious detail, but it would certainly be a good start to a problem which so far is basically just "it doesn't work". If you have an answer feel free to post it. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit turns out it's not as easy as one might assume at first, for example, 1 of the ciphers that ssllabs complain about is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA , but OpenSSL has another name for it. i'm not sure what that other name is, but i have narrowed it down to 3 candidates: either `SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA` OR `RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256` OR `RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA`- my gut feeling is that it's the last of the 3, but i haven't verified that, and just getting this far was non-trivial, i have exported  a full list of openssl's ciphers and made [this filter](https://3v4l.org/8lRqA)

Comment: @hanshenrik: see the [documentation of ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html) for a translation between the names of the ciphers. In this specific case it is just `AES128-SHA`. And you might have a look at the [Mozilla server configuration](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) to get a useful and secure cipher string.

Answer (score 2):

While there are only few information about affected TLS stacks it looks like that OpenSSL should not be vulnerable, even when using CBC ciphers.

I think what you see instead is a false positive, which is triggered by your server not matching the expectations of the test. While I don't know how the GOLDENDOODLE detection by SSLLabs works I've looked at the [original detection program from Tripwire](https://github.com/Tripwire/padcheck).

And it looks like that this script expects a proper HTTP server at the other end, i.e. one which first reads the request and then sends the response. Only, your server does it the other way: first sending the response and reading  (and ignoring) a bit of the request only after the response was sent. Such non-HTTP behavior is not taken into account (why should it) and confuses the detection which results in falsely reporting a non-existing problem.